# Плавное переключение изображения при прокрутке. Как реализовать?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не могу сообразить как реализовать такую фичу:
На странице есть, например 20 изображений

```html
<div class="wrapper-img">
    <img src="img/1.jpg">
    <img src="img/2.jpg" style="display: none;">
    <img src="img/3.jpg" style="display: none;">
    ...
    <img src="img/20.jpg" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Как по скролу добиться переключения изображений, то есть 1 - скрываем, 2 - выводим и т.д. Набрасал примерный js:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        var stackImages = $('.wrapper-img').find('img');
            // stackImages.hide().eq($(this).index()).css("display", "block"); - срабатывает один раз, то есть скрывает картинку1, делает видимой картинку 2
        for (var i = 0; i < stackImages.length; i++){
            // ...
        }
    });
});
```

Вопросы, которые появилсь:
1. Как заставить переключать изображения при прокрутке
2. Как установить через какой промежуток будет происходить переключение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Сделайте блок обберту для изображений, поместите туда изображения со значением position:absolute  (или же position:fixed);
2. Считывайте значения scrollTop - сколько пикселей вы прокрутили мышкой, если это значение > значения высоты изображения, то данной картинке ставте opasiti:0; Если > Высоты 1+2 изображения, то прячте уже второе фото и тд.